# Injecting a map of lists into configuration

Tags: yaml, quarkus, smallrye

I am trying to inject a dynamic map of lists into my Quarkus application and not sure if this is possible. I have not seen any documentation from Quarkus on this matter, so I am wondering if the `smallrye-config` even supports it.

```yaml
app:
  example:
  - key: KeyExample
    values:
    - test 1
    - test 2
    - test 3
  - key: KeyExample2
    values:
    - test 1
    - test 2
    - test 3
```

I am trying to avoid the following syntax and then performing post-processing on the configuration to achieve the desired effect:

```yaml
app:
  example:
    - KeyExample;test 1
    - KeyExample;test 2
    - KeyExample;test 3
    - KeyExample2;test 1
    - KeyExample2;test 2
    - KeyExample2;test 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, SmallRye Config does not support `Map<V, List<?>` directly (it can be added).

If you change the YAML slightly, it is possible to achieve the same result:

```
 app:
  example:
    KeyExample:
      values:
      - test 1
      - test 2
      - test 3
    KeyExample2:
      values:
      - test 1
      - test 2
      - test 3
```

And then you can provide a mapping for it like this:

```java
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "app")
interface MapListConfig {
    Map<String, Lists> example();
    
    interface Lists {
        List<String> values();
    }
}
```

Feel free to open an enhancement in https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-config/ to add the `Map<V, List<?>` support.